# Rover on a grid

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc

I have ridden to much about MVC and SOLID, so I have a mess in my head. I have written a small MVC application and I need your experience and sober mind.

index.php - Start point of my app

```
<?php
require 'libs/Bootstrap.php';
$app = new Bootstrap();
$rover = new Index();
$rover->create('input.txt');
```

Bootstar.php - mini rules fo url

```
<?php
require 'libs/Model.php';
require 'libs/Controller.php';
require 'libs/View.php';
require 'controllers/Error.php';
require 'controllers/Index.php';

class Bootstrap {

  function __construct() {

    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    if(($url[0] !== 'index' && !empty($url[0])) || !empty($url[1])){
        $error = new Error();
        return false;
    }
  } 
}
```

Model

```
<?php

class Help_model {

function __construct() {

}

 function getSide($x, $y, $d, $instruction){    
    if($instruction != ''){
        $instruction_str = str_split(trim($instruction));
        $prev = '';
        $res = [];

        foreach($instruction_str as $cmd){  
            if($d == 'N'){
                if($cmd == 'M'){
                    $y += 1;
                    $prev = '';
                }
                else if($cmd == 'R'){
                    $d = 'E';
                    $prev = 'R';
                }
                else if($cmd == 'L'){
                    $d = 'W';
                    $prev = 'L';
                }
            }
            else if($d == 'E'){
                if($cmd == 'M'){
                    $x += 1;
                    $prev = '';
                }
                else if($cmd == 'R'){
                    $d = 'S';
                    $prev = 'R';
                }
                else if($cmd == 'L'){
                    $d = 'N';
                    $prev = 'L';
                }
            }
            else if($d == 'S'){
                if($cmd == 'M'){
                    $y -= 1;
                    $prev = '';
                }
                else if($cmd == 'R'){
                    $d = 'W';
                    $prev = 'R';
                }
                else if($cmd == 'L'){
                    $d = 'E';
                    $prev = 'L';
                }
            }
            else if($d == 'W'){
                if($cmd == 'M'){
                    $x -= 1;
                    $prev = '';
                }
                else if($cmd == 'R'){
                    $d = 'N';
                    $prev = 'R';
                }
                else if($cmd == 'L'){
                    $d = 'S';
                    $prev = 'L';
                }
            }
        }

        array_push($res, $x, $y, $d);
        return $res;
    }
 }

 function readFromFile($file){
    if(file_exists($file)){
        $input = file($file);
        $output = [];

        for($i = 1; $i < count($input); $i++){
            $start_info = explode(' ', $input[$i]);

            if($i % 2 != 0){
                $x = 0;
                $y = 0;
                $d = '';
                $position = $start_info;
                list($x, $y, $d) = $position;
                $d = trim($d);
            }
            else{
                $instruction = '';
                $instruction = $input[$i];
                array_push($output, $this->getSide($x, $y, $d, $instruction));
            }   
        }
        return $output;
      }
   }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

require 'models/Help_model.php';

class Index extends Controller{

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();  
  }

  function create($media) {
    $model = new Help_model();      
    $file = $model->readFromFile($media);
    $this->view->render('index/index', array('file' => $file));
  }
}
```

View

```
<?php require 'views/header.php'; ?>
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach ($array['file'] as $files) {
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $count++;

    echo $file;
    if ($count % 3 == 0){
        echo '<br/>';
    }
  }
}
?>
<?php require 'views/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please tell us what the purpose of your application is, and retitle the question accordingly. See [ask].

Comment: It's MVC application that calculate moving algorytm. My question is: вoes my code clean? I need code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model isn't really modelling (what in the world is a `Help_model`?).  It would help a lot if it were actually a useful object.  In fact, I had to struggle to figure out what the purpose of this code was, even after I explicitly asked you.  The only hint was the variable name `$rover`, which was barely mentioned in the question.

Here is a proper model:

```
<?php

class Rover {
    function __construct($x=0, $y=0, $dir='N') {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
        $this->dir = $dir;
    }

    function moveForward() {
        switch ($this->dir) {
                            case 'N': $this->y++; break;
          case 'W': $this->x--; break;          case 'E': $this->x++; break;
                            case 'S': $this->y--; break;
        }
    }

    function turnLeft() {
        switch ($this->dir) {
                            case 'N': $this->dir = 'W'; break;
          case 'W': $this->dir = 'S'; break;    case 'E': $this->dir = 'N'; break;
                            case 'S': $this->dir = 'E'; break;
        }
    }

    function turnRight() {
        switch ($this->dir) {
                            case 'N': $this->dir = 'E'; break;
          case 'W': $this->dir = 'N'; break;    case 'E': $this->dir = 'S'; break;
                            case 'S': $this->dir = 'W'; break;
        }
    }

    function doInstructions($instructions) {
        foreach (str_split($instructions) as $cmd) {
            switch ($cmd) {
                case 'M': $this->moveForward(); break;
                case 'L': $this->turnLeft();    break;
                case 'R': $this->turnRight();   break;
            }
        }
    }

    static function processFile($filename) {
        $rovers = array();
        $lines = file($filename);

        # Ignore first line.  Every subsequent pair of lines contains a
        # starting configuration and set of instructions.
        for ($i = 1; $i + 1 < count($lines); $i += 2) { 
            list($x, $y, $dir) = explode(' ', $lines[$i]); 
            $rovers[] = $rover = new Rover(intval($x), intval($y), trim($dir));
            $rover->doInstructions($lines[$i + 1]);
        }       
        return $rovers;             
    }             
}
```

Notable changes:

- Each `Rover` object actually represents the state of a rover.
- The `processFile()` function is static; you call it as `Rover::processFile($filename)`.  What you had before…

  > ```
  > function create($media) {
  >   $model = new Help_model();      
  >   $file = $model->readFromFile($media);
  >   $this->view->render('index/index', array('file' => $file));
  > }
  > ```

  … was senseless instantiation of an object just to call a function.
- I've reorganized the `if` statements as `case` blocks, and split them up into one method per command.  The code is easier to follow if you branch primarily based on the current instruction rather than the current orientation.
- `$prev` is a pointless variable, which you assign to but never use.
- `for ($i = 1; $i < N; $i++)` needs a comment due to the weirdness of starting at 1.
- I got rid of a lot of senseless assignment of variables in `readFromFile()`, where you immediately overwrite the value afterwards.
- Wrapping your entire functions in `if ($instruction != '')` and `if (file_exists($file))` is a bad idea — it just defers crashes and makes bugs harder to trace.  You also end up returning a value in some cases and not returning a value in other cases, which puts a burden on the caller to handle both cases.
- There is no need to `trim($instruction)`.  Whitespace will be ignored as unrecognized commands anyway.

The `Rover` objects also make it possible to write a sane view that isn't trying to make sense of a linear array in chunks of three elements:

```
<?php
require 'views/header.php';
foreach ($array['result_states'] as $rover) {
    printf("%d %d %s<br/>\n", $rover->x, $rover->y, $rover->dir);
}
require 'views/footer.php';
?>
```